# Using just Marketing Cloud and Service Cloud - to have the same contacts, do I need Sales cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, servicecloud, sales-cloud

To sync the contacts in Marketing Cloud and Service Cloud, is it necessary to have the Sales cloud?

Sorry if it's a beginner question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Synchronized Data Sources work with the Sales or Service Clouds.  So you do not need to have both.

Documentation on Synchronized Objects can be found here:  [Synchronized Data Sources](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_synchronized_data_sources.htm&type=5)